# How to fetch and show data from rest api by searching in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from OpenWeatherMap by searching. the data shows like this:

```
{
"coord": {
"lon": 77.22,
"lat": 28.67
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 711,
"main": "Smoke",
"description": "smoke",
"icon": "50d"
}
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
"temp": 286.45,
"feels_like": 283.95,
"temp_min": 283.15,
"temp_max": 289.82,
"pressure": 1020,
"humidity": 66
},
"visibility": 1200,
"wind": {
"speed": 2.6,
"deg": 290
},
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"dt": 1609221695,
"sys": {
"type": 1,
"id": 9165,
"country": "IN",
"sunrise": 1609206186,
"sunset": 1609243383
},
"timezone": 19800,
"id": 1273294,
"name": "Delhi",
"cod": 200
}
```

for example if I wanna show the name and date time of the city by data.name and data.dt I can do that but in case of showing country name India by data.sys.country, It shows me the error: can't destructure property country as it is undefined. How to fix that?

Code:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
      const getData = async () => {
         try {
            setLoading(true);
            const response = await axios.get(
               "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=your_api_key&q=" +
                  search
            );
            setWeatherData(response.data);
            setLoading(false);
         } catch (error) {
            setLoading(false);
         }
      };
      getData();
   }, [search]);


const { name, dt } = weatherData;
const { country } = weatherData.sys;

return (
       <>
          <div>
            <input
               className="form-control w-50"
               type="text"
               onBlur={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
               placeholder="search products"
            />
            
            <button>Search</button>
         </div>

         
         <div>
            <h2>City Name: {name} </h2>
            <h3>Country: {country}</h3>
         </div>
        
    </>
);
```

Comment: Where did you define `weatherData`?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I have just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Link to working app: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rqr1kv), just use correct the API keys.

---

Initially, the `weatherData` sate is empty, so when you try to access the values on the first render cycle you will get that error as Axios is still working on getting the data from the server, to avoid that, you can use either conditional rendering or null propagation `(?.)` operator:

Full example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./style.css";
const API_KEY = "your API key";

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("pune");
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const getData = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=${API_KEY}&q=${search}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        setWeatherData(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log("error", error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [search]);

  // also remove it, you are trying to destructure those elements which are not present initially so they will throw an error.
  //const { name, dt } = weatherData;
  //const { country } = weatherData?.sys;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          className="form-control w-50"
          type="text"
          onBlur={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="search products"
        />

        <button onClick={getData}>Search</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>City Name: {weatherData?.name} </h2>
        <h3>Country: {weatherData?.sys?.country}</h3>
        <h2>DT : {weatherData?.dt} </h2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I will prefer the above approach.

---

Another solution is to store the initial value in the state, but if you have lot of values to deal with then this approach is not advisable.

Full example:

```
const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({
    name: "",
    dt: "",
    sys: { country: "" }
  });
```

Full Example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./style.css";
const API_KEY = "your API key";
export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("pune");
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({
    name: "",
    dt: "",
    sys: { country: "" }
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const getData = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=${API_KEY}&q=${search}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        setWeatherData(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log("error", error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [search]);

  const { name, dt } = weatherData;
  const { country } = weatherData.sys;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          className="form-control w-50"
          type="text"
          onBlur={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="search products"
        />

        <button onClick={getData}>Search</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>City Name: {name} </h2>
        <h3>Country: {country}</h3>
        <h3>DT: {dt}</h3>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: it is showing me the following error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'country' of '(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.

Comment: I am rendering ```dt``` that's why I used optional chaining, but you can omit it if you don't intend to use it.

Comment: It's working, so that means country here is an optional dynamic property while name and dt are not. And for this I have to use optional chaining ?. to access the optional dynamic property to avoid showing undefined. Right?

Comment: are you talking about the second solution with initial properties declared? if yes then I placed ```?.``` in a hurry, corrected it, it's not necessary as the `country` value is present there in the data, but just to be extra cautious I will still advise using null propagation cause you never know what kind of data you will get from api, sometimes you might end up getting empty object who knows, so just to be sure use null propagation. Your code will be less prone to errors.